# App closes when trying to view SQLiteData

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I try view data of my SQLiteDatabase on ConfirmPage the app crashes.

MainActivity:

```
DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editTeamOne, editTeamTwo, editLocation, editEmail;
Spinner editSport;
EditText editDate, editTime;
Button btnAddData, btnViewData;

private EditText TeamOne;
private EditText TeamTwo;
private TextView DateOne;
private TextView TimeOne;
private Spinner SportOne;
private EditText LocationOne;
private EditText EmailOne;



private Context context;
private Object view;
private EditText Team1;
private EditText Team2;
private Button btnSubmit;
private TextView Date1;
private TextView Time1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    TeamOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TeamTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    DateOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TimeOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    SportOne = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    LocationOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EmailOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);


    //button code to go to confirmation page
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmButton);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //OnClick of submit Team1 is required and cannot be empty
            Team1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Team1.getText())) {
                Team1.setError("Team name was not entered");
            }
            //OnClick of submit where Team2 is required and cannot be empty
            Team2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Team2.getText())){
                Team2.setError("Team name was not entered");
            }
            //OnClick of Submit where Date is required and cannot be empty
            Date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Date1.getText())){
                Date1.setError("Date was not selected");
            }
            Time1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Time1.getText())){
                Time1.setError("Time was not selected");
            }
            else {
                openConfirmPage();
                handleButtonClick();
            }

        }

    });

    //Date button
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });
    //Time Button
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
        }
    });


    //Drop down menu
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sports, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}





public void display(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.getTime());

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(currentDateString);
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    textView.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

private void handleButtonClick() {
    String strNAME = TeamOne.getText().toString();
    String strNAME2 = TeamTwo.getText().toString();
    String strNAME3 = DateOne.getText().toString();
    String strNAME4 = TimeOne.getText().toString();
    String strNAME5 = SportOne.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String strNAME6 = LocationOne.getText().toString();
    String strName7 = EmailOne.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfirmationPage.class);

    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.NAME, strNAME);
    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.NAME2, strNAME2);
    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.Date1, strNAME3);
    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.Time1, strNAME4);
    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.Sport1, strNAME5);
    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.Location1, strNAME6);
    i.putExtra(ConfirmationPage.Email1, strName7);

    startActivity(i);
}

public void openConfirmPage() {
    Intent intentCP = new Intent(this, ConfirmationPage.class);
    startActivity(intentCP);
}
```

Confirm Page:

public class ConfirmationPage extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView TeamOne;
private TextView TeamTwo;
private TextView DateOne;
private TextView TimeOne;
private TextView SportOne;
private TextView LocationOne;
private TextView EmailOne;

public static final String NAME = "team_one";
public static final String NAME2 = "team_two";
public static final String Date1 = "date";
public static final String Time1 = "time";
public static final String Sport1 = "sport";
public static final String Location1 = "location";
public static final String Email1 = "email";

DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

Button btnViewData, btnAddData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmation_page);

    DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    btnViewData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);

    TeamOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TeamTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    DateOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TimeOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    SportOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    LocationOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    EmailOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btnViewData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);

    TextView teamOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView teamTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    TextView dateOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    TextView timeOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    TextView sportOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    TextView locationOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    TextView emailOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView16);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String editText = extras.getString(NAME);
        String editText2 = extras.getString(NAME2);
        String textView = extras.getString(Date1);
        String textView6 = extras.getString(Time1);
        String spinner1 = extras.getString(Sport1);
        String editText3 = extras.getString(Location1);
        String editText4 = extras.getString(Email1);

        //If entry is not null set the text to matching id from MainActivity
        if (editText != null){
            teamOne.setText(editText);
            teamTwo.setText(editText2);
            dateOne.setText(textView);
            timeOne.setText(textView6);
            sportOne.setText(spinner1);
            locationOne.setText(editText3);
            emailOne.setText(editText4);

        }
    }

    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMatchDataPage();
        }
    });

    //ViewData();
    AddData();
};

public void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String date = DateOne.getText().toString();
            String time = TimeOne.getText().toString();
            String sport = SportOne.getText().toString();
            String team_one = TeamOne.getText().toString();
            String team_two = TeamTwo.getText().toString();
            String location = LocationOne.getText().toString();
            String email = EmailOne.getText().toString();
            int t1_score = 0;
            int t2_score = 0;


            boolean insertData = myDb.addData(date, time, sport, team_one, team_two, location, email, t1_score, t2_score);

            if (insertData == true) {
                Toast.makeText(ConfirmationPage.this, "Data Successfully Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ConfirmationPage.this, "Something went wrong :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}




public void ViewData() {
    btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor data = myDb.showData();

            if (data.getCount() == 0) {
                display("Error", "No Data Found.");
                return;

            }
            //display message

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("ID: " + data.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Date: " + data.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Time: " + data.getString(2) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Sport: " + data.getString(3) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Team One: " + data.getString(4) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Team Two: " + data.getString(5) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Location: " + data.getString(6) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Email: " + data.getString(7) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Team One Score: " + data.getString(8) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Team Two Score: " + data.getString(9) + "\n");


            }
            display("All Stored Data:", buffer.toString());
        }



    });
}

public void display(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public void openMatchDataPage() {
    Intent intentCP = new Intent(this, MatchData.class);
    startActivity(intentCP);
}

    }
```

DatabaseHelper:

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "match.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "match_table";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "DATE";
    public static final String COL3 = "TIME";
    public static final String COL4 = "SPORT";
    public static final String COL5 = "TEAM_ONE";
    public static final String COL6 = "TEAM_TWO";
    public static final String COL7 = "LOCATION";
    public static final String COL8 = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COL9 = "T1_SCORE";
    public static final String COL10 = "T2_SCORE";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDb;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    //myDb = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT, SPORT TEXT, TEAM_ONE TEXT, TEAM_TWO TEXT, LOCATION TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, T1_SCORE TEXT, T2_SCORE TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public  boolean addData(String date, String time, String sport, String team_one,
                        String team_two, String location, String email, int t1_score, int t2_score){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, date);
    contentValues.put(COL3, time);
    contentValues.put(COL4, sport);
    contentValues.put(COL5, team_one);
    contentValues.put(COL6, team_two);
    contentValues.put(COL7, location);
    contentValues.put(COL8, email);
    contentValues.put(COL9, t1_score);
    contentValues.put(COL10, t2_score);


    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}

public Cursor showData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}

public String getDetails() {

    Cursor results = myDb.query("match_table",
            new String[] {"ID", "DATE", "TIME", "SPORT", "TEAMONE", "TEAMTWO", "LOCATION", "EMAIL", "T1_SCORE", "T2_SCORE"},
            null, null, null, null, "ID");

    String resultText = "";

    results.moveToFirst();
    while (!results.isAfterLast()) {
        int id = results.getInt(0);
        String date = results.getString(1);
        String time = results.getString(2);
        String sport = results.getString(3);
        String team_one = results.getString(4);
        String team_two = results.getString(5);
        String location = results.getString(6);
        String email = results.getString(7);
        String t1_score = results.getString(8);
        String t2_score = results.getString(9);

        resultText += id + " " + date + " " + time + " " + sport + " " + team_one + " " + team_two + " " + location + " " + email + " " + t1_score + " " + t2_score + "\n";

        results.moveToNext();

    }

    return resultText;
}

public  boolean updateScore(String id, int t1_score, int t2_score) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL9, t1_score);
    contentValues.put(COL10, t2_score);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
    return true;
}

public  boolean updateData(String id, String date, String time, String sport, String team_one,
                           String team_two, String location, String email, int t1_score, int t2_score) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL2, date);
    contentValues.put(COL3, time);
    contentValues.put(COL4, sport);
    contentValues.put(COL5, team_one);
    contentValues.put(COL6, team_two);
    contentValues.put(COL7, location);
    contentValues.put(COL8, email);
    contentValues.put(COL9, t1_score);
    contentValues.put(COL10, t2_score);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
    return true;
}
```

}

MatchData:

public class MatchData extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_data);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    String details = db.getDetails();

    TextView detailsTxt = findViewById(R.id.detailsText);

    detailsTxt.setText(details);
}
```

}

2019-12-06 16:44:25.289 19399-19399/com.example.cwapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cwapp, PID: 19399
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cwapp/com.example.cwapp.MatchData}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.cwapp.DatabaseHelper.getDetails(DatabaseHelper.java:79)
        at com.example.cwapp.MatchData.onCreate(MatchData.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Answer (score 0):

You disable the initialization of `myDb` by commenting.

**Either** enable it

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    myDb = getWritableDatabase();
}
```

**Or** add `getWritableDatabase()` inside `getDetails()`

```
public String getDetails() {

    //Add this
    SQLiteDatabase myDb = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ...
}
```

Comment: @MTas, Have you checked that.